# how to use update query in to update query in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I want to update ChannelInfo what ever Reporting ChannelId update row returns
but this query is not working, giving error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""AdsReporting""
LINE : where "CampaignInfo"."id" in (update "AdsReporting" set "adS...
                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 240
```

can anyone please help me?

> Reporting ChannelId is a foreign key relationship with ChannelInfo primary key.

code:

```sql
update "ChannelInfo" set "Amount"=CASE WHEN "Duration"='60' THEN "Amount"-12.25 ELSE "Amount"-6.13 END 
where "id"=(update "Reporting" set "Status"='run' where "Status"='a' RETURNING "ChannelId");
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation fo the logic you want to implement.

Comment: This query work fine but channelInfo and Reporting has one to many relation so (select u.ChannelId from u) can return same two campaign id, so its has two minus Amount 2 times but its only minus one time.

Comment: example this is select query return

with u as (
      update "Reporting"
          set "Status" = 'run'
          where "Status" = 'a'
    RETURNING "ChannelId"
     )
update "ChannelInfo"
set "Amount"= (CASE WHEN "Duration" = '60' THEN "Amount" - 12.25 ELSE "Amount" - 6.13 END)
     where "id" in (3, 3);

its has to minus  ChannelInfo Amount twice but its only minus Amount once

Comment: Hello can you help me in this.

Comment: hello @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use CTEs:

```
with u as (
      update "Reporting"
          set "Status" = 'run'
          where "Status" = 'a'
      RETURNING "ChannelId"
     )
update "ChannelInfo" ci
    set "Amount"= (CASE WHEN ci."Duration" = '60' THEN ci."Amount" - uc.cnt * 12.25 ELSE ci."Amount" - uc.cnt * 6.13 END)
    from (select "ChannelId", count(*) as cnt
          from users u
          group by "ChannelId"
         ) uc
    where uc."ChannelId" = ci.id;
```

Comment: where "id" in (select u.ChannelId from u)  -  what if Reporting table return two same ChannelId, then it will run and minus Amount only one time because ChannelInfo and Reporting relation is one to many, so what I do, I want if its return ChannelId 2 time it will minus the amount 2 times.

Comment: @UmAiRShAhiD . . . That is really weird.  The query in the answer was not the one I wrote.  Perhaps I accidentally deleted the actual query as I saved the answer.